# Most common letter on a file (C programming)

Tags: c

I need to create a function that finds the most common letter in a file using C. 
Can't figure out my problem, for some reason it always returns `[`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char commonestLetter(char* filename);

void main()
{
    char str[101], ch;
    FILE *fout;
    fout = fopen("text.txt", "w");
    if (fout == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file\nIt's probably your fault, worked perfectly on my PC ;)\n");
        fclose(fout);
    }
    printf("Enter string (to be written on file)\n");
    gets(str);
    fputs(str, fout);
    ch = commonestLetter("text.txt");
    printf("The most common letter is %c\n", ch);
    fclose(fout);
}

char commonestLetter(char* filename)
{
    char ch;
    int i, count[26];
    int max = 0, location;
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("file is not open\n");
        return;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        count[i] = 0;

    while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
    {
        if (isalpha(ch))
            count[toupper(ch) - 'A']++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (count[i] >= max)
        {
            max = count[i];
            location = i + 1;
        }
    }
    return location + 'A';
}
```

Comment: huh??? three times same thing....why? why ? why?

Comment: `void main()`??? which era?? please use `int main(void)`.

Comment: @NatashaDutta, I think it's to beat the restriction that's put to stop questions which have too much code, too little comment.

Comment: @shebaw: It's _obvious_ that this is _not_ what the SE devs want you to do when you hit that restriction. What a silly way to write a question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I know, I was just making an observation and editing it failed because of that restriction.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I made the edit already, waiting to get accepted.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your problem? For example, with some specified input, what is the actual *and* expected output?

Comment: don't use gets; it's not possible to use safely, and for that reason has been booted out of the C standard. Use fgets instead, with stdin as third parameter.

Comment: By the way, you have an off-by-one error. Maybe that's the problem you're having?

Comment: Well,  `'['` in the ASCII character set is equal to `'Z' + 1`.    Most likely explanation is then that the most common character in your input file (which you haven't shown) is `'Z'` and you have an "off by one" error.

Comment: you should call fclose(fout) before the function call, I mean close the file pointer before the function call, because you don't need the fout after the function call.

Comment: 0) `fclose(fout);` move to before `ch = commonestLetter("text.txt");`

Comment: ``location = i + 1;`` looks off to me. Try ``location = i;`` instead.

Comment: @NatashaDutta, C11 (at least the [april draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) explicitly states that there is no prototype for the `main` function; `void main()` is legal and fine (§5.1.2.2.1, paragraph 1), although the return value is unspecified in that case (§5.1.2.2.2)

Comment: @WouterVerhelst heh? what? I can clearly see it's written `It shall be defined with a return type of int`...what you're referring to?

Comment: @NatashaDutta "The implementation declares no prototype for this function". But yeah, better form to use int, at any rate.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst so??? implementation does not define prototype means you can write it any way you want? the immediate ___It shall be defined___ should count for something no? Please read the __Conformance__ part (4.1) before reading the standard.

Comment: Sorry about the 3x thing, it was to beat the restriction. I'm fairly new here, won't be doing this again. Now I'm getting 'Z' back all the time :( Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

`location=i;`

No need of `i+1`

As you are doing `location+'A';`

Suppose the location `count[25]` has the highest count, so the location becomes `25+1=26`.

Now the `return` will be `26+65=91` which is of `'['`

The code of yours is slightly modified but the logic of your is kept

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char commonestLetter(char* filename);

int main()
{
    char str[101], ch;
    FILE *fout;
    fout = fopen("text.txt", "w");
    if (fout == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file\nIt's probably your fault, worked perfectly on my PC ;)\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Enter string (to be written on file): ");
    fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
    fputs(str, fout);
    fclose(fout);
    ch = commonestLetter("text.txt");
    printf("The most common letter is %c\n", ch);
    return 0;
}

char commonestLetter(char* filename)
{
    char ch;
    int i, count[26];
    int max = 0, location;
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("file is not open\n");
        return;
    }

    memset(&count,0,sizeof(count));
    while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
    {
        if (isalpha(ch))
            count[toupper(ch) - 'A']++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (count[i] >= max)
        {
            max = count[i];
            location = i;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return location + 'A';
}
```

Input & Output:

```
Enter string (to be written on file): Gil this is a testing
The most common letter is I
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! Now it returns 'Z' all the time :\

Comment: @Gil what is your input?

Comment: Weird, I get 'Z' all the time, even tried "this is a testing"

Comment: @Gil Did you ran my program?

Comment: Well that's embarrassing, I missed your code. It works, thanks! Any chance for an explanation of what you changed?

Comment: I changed nothing just placed the `fclose()` in right places, and made change in `line no: 15` because, if the file can't be opened then you should exit the program. I used `memset()` instead of your `for()` loop for initializing the variables to `0`(it doesn't matter just for efficiency) and and using of `fgets()` instead of `gets()`(it is not necessary but good coding practice), and as I said no logic is changed, the logic is yours. And you didn't do `fclose()` in `commonsletter()` which I did, if you don't want to do `fopen()` many times then you also have to pass the file descriptor @Gil

Comment: I still don't understand how comes your code works and mine isn't when you changes nothing critical. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Here the `line no: 15` change is so important, @Gil

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, in your code,

```
location = i + 1;
```

`location` is `i+1` at the end, and you're returning  `location + 'A';` which is (because of your input, probably) `(25+1) + 'A'` , i.e., `26 + 'A'` which is `[`.

Comment: Thanks ! But now I'm getting 'Z' every time :(